# Xdebug not stepping at breakpoints in VSCode, MAMP and Xdebug

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, mamp

Previously, my Xdebug was only stopping at the first breakpoint of my code. Then, I decided to reinstall all my set-up (simple MAMP [not PRO] and Xdebug) to try to fix it. But, actually my debugger is not even stepping at the first breakpoint.

I also have been searching and modifying the two php.ini files like I was doing before (https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/quick-tip-enabling-xdebug-in-mamp-for-osx/) but none of this work.

Here is my php.ini file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
```

My launch.json or workspace in my case:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "port": 9003
            },
            {
                "name": "Launch currently open script",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${file}",
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "port": 0,
                "runtimeArgs": [
                    "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
                ],
                "env": {
                    "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                    "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "runtimeArgs": [
                    "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                    "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                    "-S",
                    "localhost:0"
                ],
                "program": "",
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "port": 9003,
                "serverReadyAction": {
                    "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                    "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                    "action": "openExternally"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Probably is something very simple but I don't have any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Xdebug 3? Because in that case, the names of the `php.ini` settings have changed, you can find the changes in the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

In order to diagnose other issues, please try to debug a PHP file with `xdebug_info()` in it, which will tell you whether Xdebug tried to make a connection to your IDE and whether it was successful. If not, it will tell you why.

Comment: No, I'm currently using XDebug version v2.9.8. So, I cannot use the `xdebug_info()` function inside my php code. Is there any other way to see some logs errors?

Comment: Reading the guide I saw the changes that you made and it was all because of the ports. Thank you Derick for this post and also for creating such an amazing tool.

Comment: Please upgrade to Xdebug 3 though, as it will be much easier to debug issues with it.

Comment: I just uploaded today and also it works perfectly !